# CakePHP - Controller testing failed because of Security component

Tags: security, unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to test controller methods (add, edit, ...) that use Security component.

**ContactsController**

```
public function initialize() {
    $this->loadComponent('Security');
}

public function add() {
    $contact = $this->Contacts->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $contact = $this->Contacts->patchEntity($contact, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Contacts->save($contact)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__d('contact_manager', 'The contact has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__d('contact_manager', 'The contact could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('contact'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['contact']);
}
```

**ContactsControllerTest**

```
public function testAdd() {
    $data = $this->_getData();
    $this->post('/contacts/add', $data);
    $this->assertResponseSuccess();

    $query = $this->Contacts->find()->where([
        'Profiles.lastname' => $data['profile']['lastname'],
        'Profiles.firstname' => $data['profile']['firstname']
    ]);
    $this->assertEquals(1, $query->count());
}

protected function _getData() {
    $data = [
        'id' => '',
        'organization_id' => 2,
        'profile_id' => '',
        'profile' => [
            'lastname' => 'Demo',
            'firstname' => 'Demo',
            'gender' => 'f',
            'birthday' => '1990-05-20',
            'email' => 'demo@demo.com',
            'phone' => '0102030405',
            'phone_mobile' => '0607080900'
        ]
    ];
    return $data;
}
```

`testAdd()` always failed because the request is black-holed (with 'Auth' indicator), but `add()` works well in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is to be expected, as you're not sending the necessary security token, which is what the security component requires.

Just look at your generated form, it will contain hidden inputs for the `_Token` field, with the subkeys `fields` and `unlocked`, where `fields` will contain a hash and possibly the names of locked fields, and `unlocked` holds the names of unlocked fields.

Just add the token data to your request and everything should be fine. Here's an example

```
$data = [
    'id' => '',
    'organization_id' => 2,
    'profile_id' => '',
    'profile' => [
        'lastname' => 'Demo',
        // ...
    ],
    '_Token' => [
        'fields' => 'e87e3ad9579abcd289ccec2a7a42065b338cacd0%3Aid'
        'unlocked' => ''
    ]
];
```

Note that the `unlocked` key *must* be present, even if it doesn't hold any data!

You should be able to simply copy the token values from the generated form, and if you're interested in how the token is being generated and validated, have a look at **[`FormHelper::secure()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.6/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L551)**, **[`FormHelper::_secure()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.6/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L628)**, and **[`SecurityComponent::_validatePost()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.6/src/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php#L277)**.

See also **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Security](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html)**

Comment: I have added the `_Token` field with the subkeys in `$data`, so `$data` contains strictly the same keys as the generated form. But `testAdd()` fails again (with 'auth' blackhole).

Comment: @Lacos Then I'd suggest that you do some debugging, hack yourself into the security component, check where exactly it bails out, what values it retrieves, what the generated comparison hash looks like compared to the one your passing, etc... there's really not much I can do from here.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
My test fails always because of the current request URL used to generate token. This url is not the same if I launch my test in console (/contacts/add) and if I use the form in browser (/myapp/contacts/add).

Answer (score 1):

Since Cake 3.1.2 the best way is to add

```
$this->enableCsrfToken();
$this->enableSecurityToken();
```

to your TestFunction.

Doku: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-actions-protected-by-csrfcomponent-or-securitycomponent

Comment: I was getting *_Token was not found in request data*, and this fixed it. Thank you!