# Cake3: Controller TestCase is black-holed

Tags: phpunit, cakephp-3.0, csrf-protection

When I use the Security component in Cake3 I always get the error message: "*The request has been black-holed*" in my controller tests. It works as expected because the request is really black-holed in that case but I need a possibility to test my code anyway.

I found the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117598/securitycomponent-black-holing-my-controller-test-case) about the same issue but in Cake2. Unfortunately I was not able to transfer it to Cake3 and maybe it's not possible to use the same approach here.

This is how my test case looks:

```
        $data = [
        'first_name' => 'Test First Name',
        'last_name' => 'Test Last Name',
        'gender' => Gender::MALE,
        'role_id' => Role::ADMIN,
        'email' => 'test@test.com',
        'password' => '',
        'status' => Status::ACTIVE,
        'birthday' => '2015-01-01',
    ];
    $this->post(['prefix' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit', 1], $data);
```

Same problem occurs also for Csrf component but the solution should be quite similar so I will figure this out afterwards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP - Controller testing failed because of Security component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680800/cakephp-controller-testing-failed-because-of-security-component)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/31119078/1392379

Answer (score 0):

Your test must to extend IntegrationTestCase and before doing the post you could use:

```
    $this->enableCsrfToken();
    $this->enableSecurityToken();
```